# PostgreSQL - can a column in child table reference concatenation of two columns in parent table?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I have two tables. The parent table with PK(categoryID, productID):

| categoryID | productID | productName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 001 | Apples |
| 001 | 002 | Bananas |
| 002 | 001 | Laptops |

And the child table with PK(id):

| id | quantity | paid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001001 | 20 | True |
| 001002 | 15 | True |
| 002001 | 3 | False |

Can I link the child table to the parent table by defining a foreign key constraint by means of standard PostgreSQL 15 syntax?

The foreign key constraint should somehow be able to concatenate the two parent columns (categoryID, productID) to link to the "id" column of child table.

I tried with no much hope in defining the following FK inside the child table definition:

> FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES public."parent table" (categoryID) || public."parent table" (productID)

And in fact it didn't work.

The reason why I wouldn't split up the id column in child table is that, at population time, my raw data will always have a weird format that makes more convenient to me to load them concatenated.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Maybe auto generated column in parent table, something like in [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WyBuKL2Y)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a redundant generated column in the parent table with the concatenation in it and put a unique constraint on that generated column. Then the foreign key could reference that column. But that would be a high price to pay for a convenience: an additional index and a generated column, which will slow down all data modifications.

It seems simple to split the value when you load the data. If you cannot think of a way to do it outside the database, you could have a view with an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger that does the splitting and inserts into the target table.

Comment: Do you think that it's better to have a workaround to split the ids, and then store them separately inside the child table? I'm wondering if having a PK made by 2 columns can be lower in performance than having a single one, what do you think?

Comment: A two-column primary key is just fine.